# How to implement the google translator api in the dialogflow line editor

Tags: axios, dialogflow-es-fulfillment, google-translation-api

I am having problems when implementing a translator in dialogflow, I don't know what will be wrong, the code does not work for me. could you please guide me. I clarify that the line editor does not let me implement an asynchronous function.

```
const axios = require('axios'); 
const unirest = require('unirest');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');

process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements

 exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
 const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
 console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
 console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));

function translate(agent){
const text = agent.parameters.text;
const key = "yout_key";
const to = 'es';
const from = 'en';
const response = axios.post(`https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=${key}&source=${from}&target=${to}&q=${text}`);
  return response.then((result) => {
  console.log(result.text);
  agent.add("traduccion: "+result.text);
  });
  }
  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('traducir', translate);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

this is the Diagnostic info that I get in the Raw API response
{
"responseId": "7ecceeb9-9764-417a-9899-315dca16b550-b03aa3f9",
"queryResult": {
"queryText": "hello",
"parameters": {
"text": "hello"
},
"allRequiredParamsPresent": true,
"fulfillmentText": "traduccion: undefined",
"fulfillmentMessages": [
{
"text": {
"text": [
"traduccion: undefined"
]
}
}
],
"outputContexts": [
{
"name": "projects/canvas-primacy-314603/agent/sessions/d5048480-e5fb-c291-19d7-a2085d8d5fe2/contexts/text",
"lifespanCount": 5,
"parameters": {
"text.original": "hello",
"text": "hello"
}
}
],
"intent": {
"name": "projects/canvas-primacy-314603/agent/intents/b4144ec2-afd1-46bd-9347-7e20ae615f58",
"displayName": "traducir"
},
"intentDetectionConfidence": 1,
"diagnosticInfo": {
"webhook_latency_ms": 3292
},
"languageCode": "en",
"sentimentAnalysisResult": {
"queryTextSentiment": {
"score": 0.2,
"magnitude": 0.2
}
}
},
"webhookStatus": {
"message": "Webhook execution successful"
}
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before running the code I set up my intent to translate words after the colon **(:)**.
[image]

In your code, to properly get the response you should be using `result.data` to get the body of the response. The body of the response is structured this way:

```
{
   "data":{
      "translations":[
         {
            "translatedText":"translated_output_here"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Thus you can access the translated data by printing this `result.data.data.translations[0].translatedText`.

```
const text = agent.parameters.any; // This is based from my intent I used "any" as entity of words typed after the colon (:)
const key = "your_api_key";
const to = 'es';
const from = 'en';
const response = axios.post(`https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=${key}&source=${from}&target=${to}&q=${text}`);
  return response.then((result) => {
  console.log(result.data.data.translations[0].translatedText);
  output = result.data.data.translations[0].translatedText;
  agent.add("traduccion: "+ output);
  }); 
  }
```

Testing done:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with the code.  The code needs to require the needed libraries, to define agent, to include an intent map, and the function must be named dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment to use the Dialogflow fulfillment library.

You can see the Dialogflow fulfillment library docs and samples to see the required boilerplate elements [1](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs) then add your code around them.

Comment: Hello good morning, I have already added all the code used in the dialogflow editor, the libraries are added, the agent is defined, previously I only passed the code of the function, I do not know where my failure will be, it only returns translation: undefined

Comment: Can you add your result from the console.log(result.text); line?

Comment: I only get this result -> traduccion: undefined , It's like it doesn't do the translation, I don't know why, if I send it the parameter.text, in the diagnosis I get that it connects to the API, but it doesn't do the translation

Comment: Can you find a way to test if the text is being sent to the translation API?  Maybe you can check with a console.log of the key,from,to,text

Comment: Here is a sample that does what you're trying to do: 
 https://gist.github.com/CodingDoug/51030c85894b35a3495f548b1b5b0aff